# New to Sequelize, how should I go about writing a seed file given a self referencing belongsToMany relationship?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

[table schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIN6B.png). I have 3 mysql tables using sequelize, `Person`, `Location`, and `Relationship`. `Location` is very simple, with location_id being a foreign key to `Person`.  `Person` belongs to many `Person` through a `Relationship`, ie a Mother person would have a dependent relationship to a student person.  I am struggling to write a seed file that would establish these connections however:

Person model:

```
'use strict';

const RELATIONSHIP_TYPES = require('../utils/relationshipTypes');

let typeValues = Object.values(RELATIONSHIP_TYPES);

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const person = sequelize.define('person', {
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    type: { type: DataTypes.ENUM({ values: typeValues }), allowNull: false, defaultValue: typeValues[0] },
    dateOfBirth: { type: DataTypes.CHAR, field: 'date_of_birth' },
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    phone: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    intakeqId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, field: 'intakeq_id' },
    kareoId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'kareo_id' }
  });

  person.associate = (models) => {
    // Many to one relationship with location
    models.location.hasMany(person, {
      foreignKey: 'location_id'
    });
    person.belongsTo(models.location);

    // Many-to-many relationship with other people
    person.belongsToMany(person, {
      as: { singular: 'dependent', plural: 'dependents' },
      through: models.relationship,
      foreignKey: { name: 'person_id', allowNull: false }
    });
    person.belongsToMany(person, {
      as: { singular: 'dependency', plural: 'dependencies' },
      through: models.relationship,
      foreignKey: { name: 'dependent_person_id', allowNull: false }
    });
  };

  return person;
};
```

Relationship model:

```
'use strict';

const RELATIONSHIP_TYPES = require('../utils/relationshipTypes');

let typeValues = Object.values(RELATIONSHIP_TYPES);

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const relationship = sequelize.define('relationship', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false },
    type: { type: DataTypes.ENUM({ values: typeValues }), allowNull: false, defaultValue: typeValues[0]}
  });

  return relationship;
};
```

table people;

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('PATIENT','MOTHER','FATHER','TEACHER') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PATIENT',
  `date_of_birth` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intakeq_id` int NOT NULL,
  `kareo_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `people_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

table relationships;

```
CREATE TABLE `relationships` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('PATIENT','MOTHER','FATHER','TEACHER') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PATIENT',
  `person_id` int NOT NULL,
  `dependent_person_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `person_id` (`person_id`),
  KEY `dependent_person_id` (`dependent_person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `relationships_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `people` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `relationships_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dependent_person_id`) REFERENCES `people` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

table locations;

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hours` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Please show us the schema for these tables

Comment: Added an image with schemas! @RiggsFolly

Comment: I cannot copy/paste an image into my Mysql and create a set of tables to test an answer. If its text, paste it as text into the question

Comment: DO `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: Phew okay now it should be good